# Seeing the audience on Android with the Facebook SDK callback

Tags: android, facebook, audience

I'm using the standard 'Sharing in Android' tutorial from the Facebook dev site:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/

I've setup the callback onActivityResult onComplete method from the tutorial:

```
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
        Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
    }
```

What I want to do here is to know if the user posted to 'Only Me' or if they posted to their friends. Does anyone know if this is possible? I am not trying to control it, I just want to do certain actions if they only post to themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible, the Facebook app does not tell you that.